# Error : dynamic libraries not enabled check your lua installation

Tags: lua, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I am using lua on an embedded system. I have cross compiled lua interpreter for my device and other libraries.

```
require('test') 

print('script')
```

Ouptut:

> error loading module 'test' from file './test.so':
>           dynamic libraries not enabled; check your Lua installation

How i installed lua ::::

cross compilation :

#### MAKE :

```
arvindpanwar@arvindpanwar-Latitude-E5450:~/code/lua-5.3.3$ PATH=$PATH:~/.glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/lib make CC=arm-linux-gcc CFLAGS='-I/home/arvindpanwar/.sdk/include -DLUA_USE_LINUX' LDFLAGS='-L/home/arvindpanwar/.sdk/lib -lcurses' linux INSTALL_TOP=~/.sdk
```

#### MAKE INSTALL:

```
arvindpanwar@arvindpanwar-Latitude-E5450:~/code/lua-5.3.3$ PATH=$PATH:~/.glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/lib make install CC=arm-linux-gcc CFLAGS='-I/home/arvindpanwar/.sdk/include -DLUA_USE_LINUX' LDFLAGS='-L/home/arvindpanwar/.sdk/lib -lcurses' linux INSTALL_TOP=~/.sdk
```

Comment: How did you install Lua?

Comment: I cross compiled lua for my device as : arvindpanwar@arvindpanwar-Latitude-E5450:~/code/lua-5.3.3$ PATH=$PATH:~/.glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.glibc-oabi-toolchain-arm-generic/lib make CC=arm-linux-gcc CFLAGS='-I/home/arvindpanwar/.sdk/include -DLUA_USE_LINUX' LDFLAGS='-L/home/arvindpanwar/.sdk/lib -lcurses' linux INSTALL_TOP=~/.sdk

Comment: Put the code in question itself.

Comment: Does `-DLUA_USE_POSIX -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN` appear in the `make` output?

Comment: -DLUA_USE_LINUX  appears in output , not -DLUA_USE_POSIX   -DLUA_USE_DLOPEN

Comment: `-DLUA_USE_LINUX` implies `-DLUA_USE_DLOPEN` (check in `luaconf.h` to be sure), so that should be ok.

Comment: Could you please post this in the Lua mailing list with the complete output of the compilation?